# FSTAB trouble - unable to load linux system after unplugging additional hdd

Tags: linux, hard-disk, fstab, elementary-os

I have two hard drives on my computer. On one of them I have installed linux (elementaryOS) and on the second one I store some of my data. I have made fstab entry to auto-mount this drive and everything works fine until I unplug that drive to move it to another computer. After that I cannot load system at all. All I see is a blinking cursor.

my fstab entry:

```
UUID=uuid  /media/user/DATA  ntfs-3g defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1  0  2
```

what is wrong with that?

Comment: Do you see blinking cursor right after POST boot? Have you checked your BIOS/UEFI settings for boot order? Make sure PC at least tries to boot your OS.

Comment: Yes, I see blinking cursor. I have checked UEFI settings and boot order is set to hard drive with linux.

Answer (score 0):

fstab is used to mount static disks at startup (usually internal disks or disks that will never get removed).

---

#### (my suggestion)

If you're looking to mount the disk on startup *if* it is present, I would suggest using `cron`:

From `crontab -e` (edit your crontab), add the following line at the bottom:

```
@reboot mount -U <your-UUID-her>
```

Just remember to take out the offending line from `fstab`.

Comment: This is static internal disc. I don't realy move it very often, but I want to be sure, that when some day it will be broken I will be able to run my os with no problems. I found info about options I have used in fstab entry in archlinux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab Tak a look at "External devices" section. I am also wondering if there is better and more safe method than fstab like cron (as you suggested), rc.local or autostart script. What do you think about it?

Comment: If it's an old internal disk that might go anytime soon I would strongly suggest `cron`. It's what I do when I discover a disk is starting to act weird, as a precaution. I prefer `cron` over other methods because it's quite universal (works with all Unix systems).

Comment: finaly I've decided to make my own mounting script executable on startup: 

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html

and it works perfectly as I wanted :) bye bye fstab method ;)